# Url_for in a string flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to return a href in a string. I want to pass a variable to the url_for and i can't make it to work.

```
      { sortable: false,
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
            return '<a href="{{url_for('details', pr_id=row['PR Number'])}}" class="btn btn-outline-success">Show additional details</a>';
          }
        }
```

here, row['PR Number'] should return a variable that would've been used as a parameter for url_for. Any ideea about how I should do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ sortable: false,
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
            return '<a href="' + url_for('details', pr_id=row['PR Number']) + '" class="btn btn-outline-success">Show additional details</a>';
          }
        }
```

Considering you have your `url_for` method declared in the code beforehand.

Also, you have not closed all the braces properly.

Comment: I've tried and it says that url_for is not defined. I want to mention that this code is in a Javascript environment.                                                         Uncaught ReferenceError: url_for is not defined
    at render ((index):143:17)
    at jquery.dataTables.js:2642:12
    at Object.oCol.fnGetData (jquery.dataTables.js:2115:5)

Comment: You need to define a function with the name url_for that returns you the link to the row object as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make it work with the `url_for` so I've decided to do it a bit hardcoded, not the best solution, but maybe it would help someone:

```py
    return '<a href="' + window.location.origin + '/details/' + row['PR Number'] +'" class="btn btn-outline-success">Show additional details</a>';
```